# trying to get an element's position, but it's always 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, mobile, position, undefined, offset

I'm trying to get a # to use in a scrollTop function, but all I get is 'undefined'
Where have I gone wrong?

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head><body>

<div data-role="page" id="page5"  data-theme="c">
<BR><BR><BR><BR>
<p><span id="1.11.13">1.11.13</span> Lots of text here... </p>

<script>
$(window).on('pageinit', function() {
    console.log($('#1.11.13').css('top')); //undefined
    console.log($('#1.11.13').position()); // undefined
    //console.log($('#1.11.13').offset().top); = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined 
});

</script></div></body></html>
```

Comment: `$(document).on('pageinit'` not `$(window).on('pageinit'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

So either escape special character:

```
$('#1\\.11\\.13')
```

or use:

```
var id="1.11.13";
$("[id='"+id+"']")
```

Comment: :) get into 10K... +1. By the way its a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

`.` in the selector indicates a class selector, so you need to escape it since in your case it is part of the id value

You need to escape the `.` in id

```
$('#1\\.11\\.13')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VaT6E/)

else it looks for an element with id `1` and classes `11` and `13` like

```
<span id="1" class="11 13">1.11.13</span>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VaT6E/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `id` start with number is not valid HTML.

In your case if you want to remain your selector, you can escape it by `\`

```
$('#1\\.11\\.13')
```

Comment: So you are escaping it because of the usage of the number.. :) Just add this line to your answer, _since you are using meta-characters inside of the selector you have to escape it to make that selector work.._